# How to obtain location of the code being executed in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging

Trying to create a logger javascript class, that I add as a require() in other javascript files. One of the functions of this logger should be, that it writes to the console which script is currently running.

They way I thought it would execute , was that I have a path.basename(__Filename) function inside my logger, but how would I go around targeting the filename of the script executing the logger script?

Comment: When you require the logger you should pass the filename as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to know which file the script itself is in as the browser loads all the scripts under the DOM while loading the page.

```
function xyz(){
    console.log(arguments.callee.toString().match(/function ([^\(]+)/)[1]);
}
```

This should give you the name of the function that's being called as long as the function is declared in function xyz(){} format. In this case xyz.

Comment: And isn't this one is better: `arguments.callee.name`